# Are there any references to why html click() method runs synchronously?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, event-loop

I found that MDN says `dispatchEvent()` runs synchronously when [introducing dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent#notes), but haven't found any formal document like MDN or HTML Standard mentions that html `click()` method runs synchronously or synthetic event runs synchronously. Can someone share relative document with me?
I would really appreciate it a lot!

Or maybe there are some execution steps in document explains it instead of concluding directly? I noticed that both `dispatchEvent()` and `click()` would set `isTrusted` attribute as false, but not sure if the `eventListener` invoking time depends on that.

Comment: It's simply that unless otherwise noted, all methods are synchronous by default. You won't find any note that explicitly mentions it.

Comment: @MisterJojo As far as I know, the I/O event will invoke eventListener and set the callback inside it as macrotask which would be run asynchronously. click()  and dispatchEvent() are the exceptions that would be run synchronously. Some answers on stackoverflow said all synthetic events would be run synchronously. I think that might be true but didn't get any formal docs to prove it.

Comment: You lose in useless considerations. In the case of a mouse click, it must propagate from the first layer of objects and then go up towards these parents. In other words, the management of the abduction on the parent passes after that of his child(in bubble mode). It is simply deferred and not asynchronous. If you use a custom event, it does not propagate, and corresponds to a code call, which means that the code written following this call will also wait for the end of this call: it is synchronous.

Comment: @周宇恒 `click` and `dispatchEvent` are not exceptions. Rather they are not I/O events. They just run the algorithm of (synchronously) dispatching an event, which is the same algorithm that's run by tasks scheduled (for asynchronous execution) by I/O events.

Comment: @MisterJojo there is no relation between the propagation of events and their relative synchronicity. And you can very well fire bubbling synthetic events: `document.addEventListener("foo", handler); document.body.dispatchEvent(new Event("foo", { bubbles: true }))` will call `handler`.

Answer (score 1):

Every algorithm step that doesn't say ["in parallel"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#in-parallel), ["queue a task"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-task), or anything that links to these, in the specs is to be executed synchronously.*

What's in the specs algo [***dispatch** an event to target*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-dispatch) is always executed synchronously. That it comes from `EventTarget#dispatchEvent()`, `HTMLElement#click()`, or from an actual user-initiated occurrence.

What can be confusing is that for *most* cases, this *dispatch an event* algo is itself wrapped in a [*queue a task*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) call, so indeed the whole action of firing an event after an occurrence happened will be asynchronous.

For example, [when an image loads](https://%20(e.g%20%5Bwhen%20an%20image%20loads%5D%5B4%5D)) we have

> 7. [Queue an element task](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-an-element-task) on the DOM manipulation task source given the img element and following steps:
>
>    1. If restart animation is set, then restart the animation.
>    2. Set current request's current URL to urlString.
>    3. [Fire an event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-fire) named load at the img element.

Where *"queue an element task"* will call our *queue a task* algo, and *"Fire an event"* will call our *dispatch* algo.

So yes, in that case, the `load` event is fired asynchronously after the actual occurrence of the image load happened.

---

Now, if we go back to [`EventTarget#dispatchEvent()`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-eventtarget-dispatchevent) (and [`HTMLElement#click()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#dom-click), which boils down to the same with a lot event building steps), we can see that it does call the *dispatch* algorithm directly, without queuing any new task.

> The `dispatchEvent(event)` method steps are:
>
> 1. If event’s dispatch flag is set, or if its initialized flag is not set, then throw an `"InvalidStateError"` `DOMException`.
> 2. Initialize event’s `isTrusted` attribute to false.
> 3. Return the result of [dispatching](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-dispatch) event to this.

And not only does this call this algo synchronously, it even returns the result of that algorithm to the caller. So there is no way that this algorithm can be processed in parallel, the caller must get the result of calling all the handlers, synchronously.

```js
const makeEvent = (type) => new Event(type, { cancelable: true });
addEventListener("foo", (evt) => {
  console.log("foo fired");
});
console.log("return value", dispatchEvent(makeEvent("foo")));

addEventListener("bar", (evt) => {
  console.log("bar fired");
  evt.preventDefault(); // cancel the event
});
console.log("return value", dispatchEvent(makeEvent("bar")));
```

<sup>* Maybe there are other cases, but I'm not aware of these, and if they exist they would very certainly be clear enough.</sup>

Comment: thanks for your answer. it helps a lot. i wanna say most of my understanding about event loop was build on your several answers and links inside those . it surprises me that you answered this question